# PL/SQL: Statement ignored

Tags: plsql, triggers

```
create or replace trigger perform_validations
after insert or update on xx_hr_employee
for each row
begin
validation;
END;
/
```

and my procedure validation is:

```
declare
 E_ID xx_hr_employee.emp_id%type;
 E_NAME xx_hr_employee.emp_name%type;
 D_ID xx_hr_employee.dept_id%type;
 D_NAME xx_hr_employee.dept_name%type;
 S_ID xx_hr_employee.supervisor_id%type;
 S_NAME xx_hr_employee.supervisor_name%type;
 P_ID xx_hr_employee.project_id%type;
 P_NAME xx_hr_employee.project_name%type;
 SAL xx_hr_employee.salary%type;
 A xx_hr_employee.age%type;
 l_count number;
 e_count number;
procedure validation 
is
cursor my_cursor is
select EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, SUPERVISOR_ID, SUPERVISOR_NAME, PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, SALARY, AGE
from xx_hr_employee  E;
begin

open my_cursor;
loop
fetch my_cursor into E_ID, E_NAME, D_ID, D_NAME, S_ID, S_NAME, P_ID, P_NAME, SAL, A;
exit when my_cursor%notfound;
if(E_ID = 0000) then
insert into xx_stg_hr_employee( EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, SUPERVISOR_ID, SUPERVISOR_NAME, PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, SALARY, AGE) 
select EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, SUPERVISOR_ID, SUPERVISOR_NAME, PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, SALARY, AGE from xx_hr_employee
where emp_id <> 0000;
end if;
end loop;
close my_cursor;

delete from xx_stg_hr_employee WHERE (Emp_name like '% %');


UPDATE xx_stg_hr_employee SET mycol=seq_id3.NEXTVAL;

Select count(*) into l_count From xx_hr_employee
Group By  EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, SUPERVISOR_ID, SUPERVISOR_NAME, PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, SALARY, AGE 
Having Count(*) > 1;
if(l_count <> 0) then
delete from xx_stg_hr_employee where mycol NOT IN (SELECT MIN(mycol) 
    FROM xx_stg_hr_employee GROUP BY EMP_ID, EMP_NAME, DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, SUPERVISOR_ID, SUPERVISOR_NAME, PROJECT_ID, PROJECT_NAME, SALARY, AGE);

end if;

end;


 begin
    validation;
    end;
    /
```

it is showing Error at line 2: PL/SQL: Statement ignored..
here validation is a procedure which should get called when any insert(or update) is performed on xx_hr_employee..
I don't know how to proceed further.
I am using oracle apex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've tested the following and it worked for me, so please see what you missed:

For example 
Your table is like `Create table TEST_TABLE (X Number);`

Then your stored procedure is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  PROCEDURE VALIDATIONS IS
BEGIN
     --Do your validation over here..
     UPDATE TEST_TABLE SET X = 1;
END;
```

then your code should work as you written:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER PERFORM_VALIDATIONS
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON TEST_TABLE 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 VALIDATIONS;
END;
/
```

**Important:** If you create the procedure in a package, then make sure that the Package head has the declaration, and then call it like `YourPackageName.VALIDATIONS`  instead of `VALIDATIONS` only

Comment: everything is same as you have mentioned except updating variable X inside procedure. Is this make any difference? My code is still giving the same error.

Comment: No this is just an example, Did you create the procedure in a package?

Comment: No....i haven't used any package here..just a simple procedure which performs some validations when data is transferred from one table to another.thats it. totally stuck in this.

Comment: Could you check whether you can run the stored procedure alone without error.

Comment: yup.it is compiling without any error.but one thing is there.I have called the procedure twice.Under a begin block which is inside my procedure and then inside my trigger. Is this is causing the problem ??

Comment: Make sure not to make cycle call, also, put the code so I can see the whole picture..